# Multiple databases with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

We are trying to implement Kubernetes in our system and we have two mysql databases and two services.

One service should be able to connect to both databases and the other uses just one.

So `auth-service`->`key-db` and `transaction-service`->`key-db + pdns-db`.

I currently the databases running and both exposing port `3306` (default mysql) with hostname `key-db` and `pdns-db`. The `auth-service` is able to connect to the `key-db` fine. But when I try to start the `transaction-service` which connects to `key-db:3306` and `pdns-db:3306` it fails.

We don't want to expose the databases so we didn't gave them a Cluster IP.
I'm pretty new to this stuff so I guess I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Theo

Answer (score 2):

You have to put a Service in front of any Pod that you want to connect to from anywhere, even within the cluster.  If you declare it a ClusterIP type (the default) it will only be reachable from within the cluster.  You have to explicitly set up the service as a NodePort or LoadBalancer type if you want it to be reachable from outside.

Comment: I know what the problem it. Both database services have exactly the same yaml configuration but different database names and passwords. Every time I try to connect to one of them it ether uses the `pdns-db` or `keyshake-db`. When I removed the `pdns-db` it works as normal. See attached images: https://imgur.com/a/oZjP8HA . I don't know how to fix this..